# How to configure my proxy client so that it behaves like a WebClient (authentication)?

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, cxf, webclient

I'm trying to consume a java webservice which require authentication in C#.

I was able to send raw SOAP with a WebClient :

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(MyUsername, MyPassword);
    // ...
}
```

But I can't do it with a proxy generated by the svcutil tool :

```
using (var client = new MyInterfaceClient(endpoint))
{
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = MyUsername;
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = MyPassword;
    // ...
}
```

I want to configure the proxy in order that the behavior of the proxy is the same as the WebClient. I already tried some bindings like but it just don't work:

```
<binding name="MyBinding">
  <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
  </security>
</binding>
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Fiddler to see how exactly your working request looks like in terms of HTTP headers. Than compare it to the request your WCF generates. You can publish the results here.

Comment: I saw a Authorization Basic header with Wireshark (already installed it before you told me to use Fiddler), and I managed to create this header with the web.config (see edit). Thanks.